# Page keeps reloading instead of setinterval with generated time

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a basic script to refresh page in random time interval and clicks a button.

So I wrote a code with `reload()` function,

```
function() {window.location.reload;}
```

the code;

```
else if (pathname === "/x.aspx/y" || pathname === "/x.aspx/y/111111")
    {
    document.getElementById("ctl00_cphTopColumn_ctl00_btnUseItem").click();
    var delay = Math.random()*120000
    var wait = ( 600000+delay )
    console.log (wait/60000 + " dakika sonra yenilenecek " )
    var myVar = setInterval(reload(), wait)
    }
```

**Issue :** Instead of waiting for a time interval it continuously refreshes page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reload()` -> `() => reload()`

```
else if (pathname === "/x.aspx/y" || pathname === "/x.aspx/y/111111")
    {
    document.getElementById("ctl00_cphTopColumn_ctl00_btnUseItem").click();
    var delay = Math.random()*120000
    var wait = ( 600000+delay )
    console.log (wait/60000 + " dakika sonra yenilenecek " )
    var myVar = setInterval(() => reload(), wait)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of you are calling `reload()` function immediately.

Call `reload()` function in the callback of `setInterval` like this:

```
 var myVar = setInterval(() => reload(), wait);
```